# Add additional key and value on arrays if condition is met

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array(
    Array(
          [name] => John
          [last] => Smith
          [status] => sent
         )
    Array(
          [name] => Jane
          [last] => Doe
          [status] => pending
         )
    Array(
          [name] => Kripky
          [last] => Woe
          [status] => pending
         )
)
```

Code:

```
   $arr = array();
   foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
        if($value['status'] == 'sent'){
            $arr[] = array($value, $value['dupe'] = 1); 
        }
    }
```

How to add `$value['dupe'] = 1` on all arrays if there is one `status = sent` on an array

Expected result:

```
Array(
    Array(
          [name] => John
          [last] => Smith
          [status] => sent
          [dupe] => 1
         )
    Array(
          [name] => Jane
          [last] => Doe
          [status] => pending
          [dupe] => 1
         )
    Array(
          [name] => Kripky
          [last] => Woe
          [status] => pending
          [dupe] => 1
         )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop should do it for you:

```
foreach ($a as $i) {
    if ($i['status'] == 'sent') {
        foreach ($a as &$_i) {
            $_i['dupe'] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[**`Example Demo`**](https://eval.in/173365)

---

**Note:** This uses variable by reference (`&`) so it will update the actual array.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
// first, define a function that tells if there is a statut = sent
function statut_exist($arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $value) 
        if($value['status'] == 'sent')
          return true;
    return false;
}

// then add the dupe if there is a statut = sent
if(statut_exist())
    foreach ($res as $value) 
        $value['dupe'] = 1
```